# Migrate application from jetty server to wildfly 10 server

Tags: java, jetty, wildfly

I have to deploy Jetty based application into Wildfly server10. Since, Jetty application has inbuilt Jetty server configurations in java class and when I execute pom.xml, will get Jar file. So, now I need to move Jetty application to wildfly. Could someone help to how to migrate Jetty to Wildfly? I did google but I couldn't able to find the exact answers.

Comment: If you're looking for an executable JAR have a look at WildFly Swarm http://wildfly-swarm.io. If that's not what you're looking for a lot more information would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to migrate your application firstly you have to change the packaging of your Maven project, from JAR to WAR. Then you can migrate the configuration to a web.xml, but it depends on what you have written in your Jetty conf. For example the Servlet mapping in Jetty

```
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.addServlet(mypackage.HelloServlet.class, "/hello");
```

must be translated to a configuration in web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

or with an annotation in your servlet class

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Federico Paparoni, the solution got worked out for me.